# jq: unnesting records and mixing fields from both record levels

Tags: json, jq

I have the following file:

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'arr': [{'x': 1,
                {'x': 2}]
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'arr': [{'x': 3},
                {'x': 4}]
    }
]
```

How can I transform it into the following form using jq?

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'x': 1},
    {'id': 1, 'x': 2},
    {'id': 2, 'x': 3},
    {'id': 2, 'x': 4},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it doesn't get any more complex than that, you could simply do this:

```
map(del(.arr) + .arr[])
```

This is under the assumption that you're replacing the `arr` property of each object with the contents of the items in `arr`. It's unclear what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The input shown in the question is not valid JSON.  After making some minor changes to make it valid JSON, the following filter produces the output as shown below:

```
map( (.arr[]|.x) as $x | {id, "x": $x} )
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "x": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "x": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "x": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "x": 4
  }
]
```